# Is it ok to initialize jQuery object twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a function that expects a jQuery object, but want to also accept selector strings and elements for convenience. So I am doing something like this:

```
test($('.something'));
test('.something');
test($('.something')[0]);

function test (param1) {
  //ensure jquery object
  if (!(param1 instanceof $)) {
    param1 = $(param1);
  }

  //do something with $param1
}
```

Would it hurt to just initialize the jQuery object regardless or are there implications and performance issues with this?

```
function test (param1) {
  //ensure jquery object
  param1 = $(param1);

  //do something with $param1
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of them will work. But if you are looking for the best option you should go with the first function. [Check this out](http://jsperf.com/jquery-object-initialization).

**Update**

[Here it is the perf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-object-initialization/2) with corrections by the OP and one extra test I didn't think in.

Comment: Thanks. I've just added each of the three cases with each of the two function. So we can see in which cases we lose, and in which cases we win. The bad side: it takes some time to run the tests because now there are 8 :(

Comment: Thanks this was awesome! I think there was a bug in my code tho.. I think it should be "if (!(param1 instanceof $))" otherwise it is checking it is turning param1 to a boolean before checking if it is jQuery. I fixed the code and they are closer but checking a jQuery object is the fastest without reinitializing. I also added a ternary case and that actually performed better in some case :) http://jsperf.com/jquery-object-initialization/2

Comment: That's great! I'll now update the link of the perf in my answer.

Comment: The way your tests have been conducted is flawed; the tests should reflect that a jQuery object is expected, that means changing the probability between both "modes". If you're not sure what that means, look at the jsperf results in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate jQuery with another jQuery element, it will return a shallow copy of the latter. Inside the constructor, after determining that the selector is not a string or DOM element, `jQuery.makeArray()` is called [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L189). This in turn calls `jQuery.merge()` [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L655) to make the shallow copy.

This obviously takes up precious cycles, especially since you're **expecting** a jQuery object as your argument. It therefore makes a lot more sense to use `instanceof` to determine the type first.

How much more sense? Assuming there's a 20% chance that the argument is NOT a jQuery object, doing a type check will yield a **6x performance boost** (based on Chrome).

Take a look at the [results](http://jsperf.com/jquery-double-init).

Comment: Nice very pretty precise and there's a huge difference. I added a ternary case and performs just about as good as the if-statement. That means assigning a variable to itself every time is negligible for the sake of shortening code: http://jsperf.com/jquery-double-init/2

Comment: @TruMan1 I don't like to use ternary operators for noops :) but it probably won't hurt your performance much either way.